# Как поменять base

Tags: git

У меня идет моя ветка от master а мне нужно чтобы шло от другой ветки branchn, хотя она и идентичная master.

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase branchn
```

Выдает is up to date.

Что сделать?

Comment: git rebase branchn/master не?

Answer (score 2):

Все знаю ответ. В отличии от меркуриал, в гите и та и та ветка указывает на один коммит поэтому сделано все верно. И ребейс делать не нужно.